# How to view javascript console logs within a Ionic App WKWebView using Safari (or other tool)

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, wkwebview

I am faced with a dilemma.  I have an iOS/Android built using ionic 5 (using Cordova tools). We are using the cordova-plugin-ionic-webview plugin.  I am trying to access the WebViews on the app, so I can view the underlying javascript in the console.

However, when I use Safari developer, nothing is showing up under my phone's menu.

Preconditions:

1. Safari -> Advanced -> Web Inspector enabled (iOS 14.4.2 - latest as of this writing)
2. Xcode Version 12.0 (12A7209)
3. Cordova iOS version: iOS 6.2.0

Steps I followed:

- Building the app using Xcode (debug mode only, using Adhoc license)
- Installing the app on my phone using Apple Configurator 2 (AC2)
- Launching latest Safari 14.03 -> Develop -> my phone -> says "No Inspectable Applications"
- NEXT launched Safari Technology Preview (Release 123 (Safari 14.2, WebKit 16612.1.7.10)) -> Develop -> my phone -> says "No Inspectable Applications"

I don't know what else to do.

In short, how do I view the javascript console logs from my app? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: do you also have latest version of xcode installed?

Comment: Yes.  Updated my original post

Comment: what version of Cordova IOS are you using? try `ionic cordova platform ls` and add result to your question.

Comment: Updated with ios 6.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Launch your app on a simulator, then open Google Chrome and in the url bar type:

chrome://inspect/#devices

You should see your device in the list, and you can click on inspect to get the console.log

Comment: I doubt that chrome can debug an iOS app based on wkwebview, or does it?